# How to invoke a method in a view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

Just getting started with SwiftUI.

I have a [GoogleMapsView](https://gist.github.com/kwmt/1df17577c59e33da1c4c2eb982f21bbf) in a `ContentView`
using the `CLLocationManager` I capture events in the `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` class by means of extending them with `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

How can I invoke a method in the `GoogleMapsView` from the `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`?

In this instance I want to call the `.animate` method when the location change event is sent to the `AppDelegate` instance via the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, but the question is really more generic.

Comment: For animating a location change, could the location data be in a `@State` or `@ObservedObject` variable within the view? The idea here would be that changes to this state would automatically update the view, so then the view's changes could use an  `.animation()` ViewModifier.

Comment: The .animate method would be called on the GoogleMapsView object (its internal MapView, actually), to show the map centred on a different position. It isn't really an animation that I'd have control over as it is provided by the MapView itself.
The more generic question is how how to invoke a View method from AppDelegate or SceneDelegate.

Comment: It seems like I'll have to look in the Combine element of the new SwiftUI paradigm.

Comment: I have not had a chance to look into GoogleMapsView, but as a `UIViewRepresentable` I wonder what it's extensibility on that front is.

Comment: By the provided link is not clear what and where and on which condition are you going to call. Show in comments in pseudo-code what do you want to achieve.

Comment: You mention that you capture events in the `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` class by means of extending them with `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, but I don't see this in your question. Can you please provide this implementation so we can better help you resolve what you're after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made and implementation of CLLocationManager and MKMapView and it is almost the same as maps, hope it will help you:

**Short answer**: declaring a `@Binding var foo: Any` you will be able to make changes inside GoogleMapView every time that foo changes, in this case foo is your location, so you can call animate every time foo is updated.

**Long answer**:

First I created a Mapview that conforms UIViewRepresentable protocol, just as you did, but adding a @Binding variable, this is my "*trigger*".

**MapView**:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var location: CLLocation // Create a @Binding variable that keeps the location where I want to place the view, every time it changes updateUIView will be called
    private let zoomMeters = 400

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        //When location changes, updateUIView is called, so here I move the map:
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate,
                                        latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: zoomMeters)!,
                                        longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: zoomMeters)!)
        mapView.setRegion(mapView.regionThatFits(region), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Then I placed my MapView in my ContentView, passing a location argument, which I will explain next:

**ContentView**:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView(location: self.$viewModel.location)
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel, I handle location changes using a delegate, here is the code with more details in comments:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //location is a Published value, so the view is updated every time location changes
    @Published var location: CLLocation = CLLocation.init()

    //LocationWorker will take care of CLLocationManager...
    let locationWorker: LocationWorker = LocationWorker()

    init() {
        locationWorker.delegate = self
    }

}

extension ContentViewModel: LocationWorkerDelegate {
    func locationChanged(lastLocation: CLLocation?) {
        //Location changed, I change the value of self.location, it is a @Published value so it will refresh the @Binding variable inside MapView and call MapView.updateUIView
        self.location = CLLocation.init(latitude: lastLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation!.coordinate.latitude)
    }
}
```

And finally here is LocationWorker which take cares of CLLocationManager():

```
class LocationWorker: NSObject, ObservableObject  {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var delegate: LocationWorkerDelegate?

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        //...
    }
}

protocol LocationWorkerDelegate {
    func locationChanged(lastLocation: CLLocation?)
}

extension LocationWorker: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.lastLocation = location
        //When location changes: I use my delegate ->
        if delegate != nil {
            delegate!.locationChanged(lastLocation: lastLocation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, this is exactly what I was after. I did get that in this new paradigm the views shouldn't be manipulated externally by means of getting references, but got lost when trying to wire everything up with Combine.

Comment: I know this thread is a few months old, but was hoping I could ask a question related to accessing a View from ViewModel. When using UIViewRepresentable to represent a MapView, the ability for the ViewModel to access the required mapView object to add overlays, etc is gone.... How can I tell the uiview to add an overlay on behalf of the viewmodel or call it directly to access mapView object?

Comment: @Tim you can pass another `@Binding` variable to control your overlay maybe `@Binding var :showOverlay = false`, every time you update it updateUIView will be called and there you decide to show your overlay or not.

Comment: zgluis, Thanks for the response. I got it to work by setting the polyline I create in viewmodel to @Published and then accessing the overlay in updateUI where I have access to mapview. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a `View` method directly from outside, you should revise your logic a bit and just change some kind of a `state` somewhere and let the `View` update itself. Take a look at this algorithm:

---

#### The classic (and worst) way:

1. Location changed
2. Delegate method called in the app delegate (Better refactor to else where)
3. App delegate calls a method directly on the `view` (You should pass a reference to that `view` all the way up to the app delegate)

<sub>Although the above algorithm is what you are looking for originally, It isn't the best way and I don't recommend it at all! But it will work ‍♂️</sub>

---

## The SwiftUI way:

1. Location changed
2. Delegate method called in the responsible object (maybe a singleton location location manager instance ‍♂️)
3. Location manager updates a `State` somewhere. (maybe an `ObservedObject` variable inside itself or an `EnvironmentObject` or etc.)
4. All views that subscribed for changes of that property will notify about the changes
5. All notified views will update themselves.

This is how it should be done. But there are more than just one way to implement this and you should consider your preferences to pick the best for you.

Comment: I did try to go "the SwiftUI" but got lost on the way. The example from @zgluis made it all very clear. Thank you.